# How can I populate a reactive form when I click on the edit button for the following project structure using Angular?

Tags: angular, crud, edit

I'm creating a simple todo app using Angular and reactive forms and I can't figure out how to populate the form when the "edit" button is clicked in following project structure.

**Project structure:**

- App

  - shared

    - task-detail.model.ts
    - task-detail.service.ts
  - task-details

    - task-details-form

      - task-details-form.component.html -> contains the reactive form
      - task-details-form.component.ts
    - task-details.component.html
    - task-details.component.ts

So the task-details.component.html contains the list of all the todos and each todo item has "Edit" and "Delete" buttons.

Here is my task-details.component.html

```
<app-task-detail-form></app-task-detail-form>

<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let t of service.listOfItems">
       {{t.title}} = {{t.isCompleted}} 
       <button (click)="onDelete(t.taskId)">Delete</button> 
       <button (click)="populate(t)">Edit</button> 
   </li>  
</ul>
```

My question is:

**How can I populate the reactive form in task-details-form.component.html when I click on the populate(t) which is in the task-details.component.ts. I know I have to send the "t" from task-details.component.html to task-details-form.component.html, but how can I do that when I have the above project structure?**

Comment: (Clearly structured. In my book, bold for **My question is** instead of all of the sum-up question would have done nicely.)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the todo to `<app-task-detail-form>` as [an input](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

### task-details.component.html

```
<app-task-detail-form [todo]="selectedTodo"></app-task-detail-form>
```

### task-details-form.component.ts

```
export class TaskDetailFormComponent {

@Input() todo: Todo;
```

### task-details.component.ts

```
selectedTodo: Todo;
populate(todo:Todo){
   this.selectedTodo = todo;
   //... the rest of your code in populate
}
```

#### Final words

The project structure is not relevant to any sort of solution here. As long as your components are declared in app.module.ts, they can be wherever.